# When running the server, my plugin does not show up in minecraft (Intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Hello I am new to Minecraft coding I just started today and I'm trying to make a spigot Minecraft plugin. When I start my server using Intellij it starts, but when I do /plugins it says "Plugins (0):" that means there is no plugins so how do I add my plugin to the plugins folder or with code or something?

Here is my main java file:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEkwD.png)

And Here is my plugin.yml file:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLZ5r.png)

Help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using apache maven, you have to run `package` command, then go to `/target` folder, and you move the built .jar file to plugin folder of your server. Only then you can start your sever. Also, please provide server logs the next time you are asking question.

tldr; `package` -> move your .jar file from /target to /plugins

Also your code is wrong:

```java
Player player = null; // player is now null, you cannot send message to null player. This is bad.
```

should be

```java
Player player = (Player) commandSender; // cast command sender to player, that is good. You can now send message.
```

[Watch this tutorial to help you.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVySbfryiMM&list=PLAF3anQEEkzREsHA8yZzVhc3_GHcPnqxR)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224319/discussion-on-answer-by-rgnt-when-running-the-server-my-plugin-does-not-show-up).